# Strange behaviour of ++ operator in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, operators

Watch following code:

```
$a = 'Test';
echo ++$a;
```

This will output:

```
Tesu
```

Question is, why ?

I know "u" is after "t", but why it doesn't print "1" ???

PHP Documentation:

> Also, the variable being incremented
> or decremented will be converted to
> the appropriate numeric data
> type—thus, the following code will
> return 1, because the string Test is
> ﬁrst converted to the integer number
> 0, and then incremented.

Comment: Printing `1` after incrementing a string would be strange.

Comment: @David Titarenco - My guess is that Michal expects the ++ to cause an implicit cast of the string to integer and, similarly to an explicit cast, yield 0. Not an unreasonable expectation, come to think of it, since ++ is a math operator.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: `$a + 1` is not the same as `++$a` or `$a++`.

Comment: @BoltClock's how enlightening. Care to read whole thread?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - Great example. Added it (no pun intended) to my answer. Strings can be incremented, using the increment operator, but they cannot be "added to" except with concatenation.

Comment: @Peter it is not great and not an example. I have just pointed out that David's comment is senseless and arrogant - **there is nothing "strange" in such a supposition.** That's all what I have said. But as usual, nobody cares to read. Everyone just want to teach. I wish there was such an activity in really important questions, not in such crappy ones.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - I thought it was an important statement, since if `++$a` does something, it seems like a safe assumption that `$a += 1` would do the same thing... which, I thought was your point.

Comment: I asked becouse i found following in famous Zend Certification Study Guide: "Also, the variable being incremented or decremented will be converted to the appropriate numeric data type—thus, the following
code will return 1, because the string Test is ﬁrst converted to the integer number 0,
and then incremented":
$a = ’Test’;
echo ++$a;

Comment: Always be sure to check back with the publisher for documents containing the errata (this particular one has been noted).  Mistakes happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PHP you can increment strings (but you cannot "increase" strings using the addition operator, since the addition operator will cause a string to be cast to an `int`, you can only use the increment operator to "increase" strings!... see the last example):

So `"a" + 1` is `"b"` after `"z"` comes `"aa"` and so on.

So after `"Test"` comes `"Tesu"`

You have to watch out for the above when making use of PHP's automatic type coercion.

### Automatic type coercion:

```
<?php
$a="+10.5";
echo ++$a;

// Output: 11.5
//   Automatic type coercion worked "intuitively"
?>
```

### No automatic type coercion! (incrementing a string):

```
<?php
$a="$10.5";
echo ++$a;

// Output: $10.6
//   $a was dealt with as a string!
?>
```

---

You have to do some extra work if you want to deal with the ASCII ordinals of letters.

If you want to convert letters to their ASCII ordinals use **[ord()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)**, but this will only work on one letter at a time.

```
<?php
$a="Test";
foreach(str_split($a) as $value)
{
    $a += ord($value);  // string + number = number
                        //   strings can only handle the increment operator
                        //   not the addition operator (the addition operator
                        //   will cast the string to an int).
}
echo ++$a;
?>
```

### **[live example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NIr8BI)**

The above makes use of the fact that strings can only be incremented in PHP. They cannot be increased using the addition operator. Using an addition operator on a string will cause it to be cast to an `int`, so:

### Strings cannot be "increased" using the addition operator:

```
<?php
   $a = 'Test';
   $a = $a + 1;
   echo $a;

   // Output: 1
   //  Strings cannot be "added to", they can only be incremented using ++
   //  The above performs $a = ( (int) $a ) + 1;
?>
```

The above will try to cast "`Test`" to an `(int)` before adding `1`. Casting "`Test`" to an `(int)` results in `0`.

---

Note: You **cannot decrement strings**:

> Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII characters (a-z and A-Z) are supported.

The previous means that `echo --$a;` will actually print `Test` without changing the string at all.

---

Comment: Good edit,but, to put a fine point to it, the string is "added to", i.e. in your code 1 is added to 0 (the post-cast value of "Test). For example try echo '7test' + 0;

Comment: @GZipp - Well, how would you explain the difference? "Strings can only be added to using the increment operator, but not the addition operator."?

Comment: I think "added to" there means concatenation.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: `$a + 1` performs an implicit type cast on `$a` before adding `1`, because there are two explicit operands in that expression and `+` is as you said not the concatenation operator in PHP. Thus it's equivalent to `(int)$a + 1`.

Comment: I know what the concatenation operator in PHP is. And I misread your previous post. My apologies. I was trying to say that in your code the addition is effectively 0 + 1, which I'm sure you know.

Comment: @GZipp - Thanks for pointing that out. I was just trying to come up with a succinct but accurate way to explain all that....

Comment: I was also trying to say that a string can be added to (mathematically) in this sense: "7test" + 1 will return 8.

Comment: @GZipp - But "7test" is cast to the int 7 before one is added to it, so you're actually performing the addition operation on an int and not on a string. --------- `gettype("7test" + 1)` will return `integer`. --------- It just depends on the result of the cast, for example `"test7" + 1` will return 1.

Comment: Yeah, Peter, that's why I used the phrase "in this sense".

Answer (score 23):

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in Perl 'Z'+1 turns into 'AA', while in C 'Z'+1 turns into '['  ( ord('Z') == 90, ord('[') == 91 ). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII characters (a-z and A-Z) are supported.

Source: http://php.net/operators.increment

Answer (score 2):

The increment operator in PHP works against strings' ordinal values internally. The strings aren't cast to integers before incrementing.