# PHP - Erroneous Alphabet Loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, alphabetical

Can Anyone Explain me why :

```
    <?php
    for ($i = 'a'; $i <= 'z'; $i++){
    echo "$i ";
    }
    ?>
```

Why its Output is :

> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa ab ac ad ae af
>   ag ah ai aj ak al am an ao ap aq ar as at au av aw ax ay az ba bb bc
>   bd be bf bg bh bi bj bk bl bm bn bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by bz
>   ca cb cc cd ce cf cg ch ci cj ck cl cm cn co cp cq cr cs ct cu cv cw
>   cx cy cz da db dc dd de df dg dh di dj dk dl dm dn do dp dq dr ds dt
>   du dv dw dx dy dz ea eb ec ed ee ef eg eh ei ej ek el em en eo ep eq
>   er es et eu ev ew ex... on to yz

But its Working Fine With

```
    <?php
    for ($i = 'a'; $i != 'aa'; $i++){
    echo "$i ";
    }
    ?>
```

The loop seems to run over and over again until it reaches "zz".

If I give `$i<"aa"` it should work fine but instead it outputs only "a".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour of ++ operator in PHP 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799549/strange-behaviour-of-operator-in-php-5-3)

Comment: You could always use the `range()` function: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: @RichardLivingston Even I dodn't! :D One of my friends showed it to me!

Comment: Much better duplicate: [Why doesn't this code simply print letters A to Z?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098345/why-doesnt-this-code-simply-print-letters-a-to-z)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the manual for the [increment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations
>   on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a =
>   'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into
>   '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that
>   character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so
>   only plain ASCII characters (a-z and A-Z) are supported.
>   Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the
>   original string is unchanged.

Comment: OK. I understand that. But even so, the loop should stop when it hits `$i < 'z'`. How does it go on an on?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - [It does stop](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eE7DNe)

Comment: Whoops! My Bad! It should be `$i <= 'z'` Why does it go on to "aa ab... " and so on?! 
The loop should stop since it has reached "z" and echoed it. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @maxxon15: Because it's a lexical (i.e. alphabetical) comparison. `aa` is "less than" `z` because it would come first when you alphabetize them. The reason it stops at `yz` is because the next string would be `za`, which comes after (is "greater than") `z` alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a less than (`$i < "aa"`) operator on a string.

It will get converted to a numerical type and the results are usually unpredictable.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @maxxon15: because `aa` is not a letter of the alphabet... Is `z` < `aa`? If you consider your sequence, yes it is, if you consider alphabetical order, no it is not. So the comparison is not really meaningful. Using `==` or `!=` of course, is another story as you can clearly define identity for strings.

Comment: @nico Hm ... That clears a lot of things. That is probably the reason why it gives only "a" when I give `$i<"aa"` and doesn't even do the normal sequence of a to z 

O_o

Comment: If that's all you're trying to do, you can just `echo 'a b c d ...';` or `echo implode(' ', range('a', 'z'));`

Comment: @Benjam - Yeah ... will use the `range()` function from now on ... :)

Comment: @nico: That comparison is entirely meaningful in PHP. `z` is greater than `aa` because it performs a lexical comparison. It doesn't matter that one is two letters and the other is only one, they're still both strings.

Comment: @eldarerathis: sorry, I may have given the wrong impression with my previous comment. I am saying that it is not meaningful to use <= in the way the OP is using, not that PHP gives unpredictable results.