# The char 'z' and FOR loop

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - Erroneous Alphabet Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360736/php-erroneous-alphabet-loop)

PHP code:

```
for ($i = 'v'; $i <= 'y'; $i++)
        echo $i . ' ';
```

Will print:

```
v w x y
```

But:

```
for ($i = 'v'; $i <= 'z'; $i++)
        echo $i . ' ';
```

Will print:

```
v w x y z aa ab ac ad ae af ag ah ai aj ak al am an ao ap aq ar as at au av aw ax ay az ba bb bc bd be bf bg bh bi bj bk bl bm bn bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by bz ca cb cc cd ce cf cg ch ci cj ck cl cm cn co cp cq cr cs ct cu cv cw cx cy cz da db dc dd de df dg dh di dj dk dl dm dn do dp dq dr ds dt du dv dw dx dy dz ea eb ec ed ee ef eg eh ei ej ek el em en eo ep eq er es et eu ev ew ex ey ez fa fb fc fd fe ff fg fh fi fj fk fl fm fn fo fp fq fr fs ft fu fv fw fx fy fz ga gb gc gd ge gf gg gh gi gj gk gl gm gn go gp gq gr gs gt gu gv gw gx gy gz ha hb hc hd he hf hg hh hi hj hk hl hm hn ho hp hq hr hs ht hu hv hw hx hy hz ia ib ic id ie if ig ih ii ij ik il im in io ip iq ir is it iu iv iw ix iy iz ja jb jc jd je jf jg jh ji jj jk jl jm jn jo jp jq jr js jt ju jv jw jx jy jz ka kb kc kd ke kf kg kh ki kj kk kl km kn ko kp kq kr ks kt ku kv kw kx ky kz la lb lc ld le lf lg lh li lj lk ll lm ln lo lp lq lr ls lt lu lv lw lx ly lz ma mb mc md me mf mg mh mi mj mk ml mm mn mo mp mq mr ms mt mu mv mw mx my mz na nb nc nd ne nf ng nh ni nj nk nl nm nn no np nq nr ns nt nu nv nw nx ny nz oa ob oc od oe of og oh oi oj ok ol om on oo op oq or os ot ou ov ow ox oy oz pa pb pc pd pe pf pg ph pi pj pk pl pm pn po pp pq pr ps pt pu pv pw px py pz qa qb qc qd qe qf qg qh qi qj qk ql qm qn qo qp qq qr qs qt qu qv qw qx qy qz ra rb rc rd re rf rg rh ri rj rk rl rm rn ro rp rq rr rs rt ru rv rw rx ry rz sa sb sc sd se sf sg sh si sj sk sl sm sn so sp sq sr ss st su sv sw sx sy sz ta tb tc td te tf tg th ti tj tk tl tm tn to tp tq tr ts tt tu tv tw tx ty tz ua ub uc ud ue uf ug uh ui uj uk ul um un uo up uq ur us ut uu uv uw ux uy uz va vb vc vd ve vf vg vh vi vj vk vl vm vn vo vp vq vr vs vt vu vv vw vx vy vz wa wb wc wd we wf wg wh wi wj wk wl wm wn wo wp wq wr ws wt wu wv ww wx wy wz xa xb xc xd xe xf xg xh xi xj xk xl xm xn xo xp xq xr xs xt xu xv xw xx xy xz ya yb yc yd ye yf yg yh yi yj yk yl ym yn yo yp yq yr ys yt yu yv yw yx yy yz
```

Why doesn't it print simply `v w x y z`?

Comment: Very interesting. This is one of those language features I would probably never ever use, owing to its unpredictability and poor documentation. I believe the character incrementing rules are designed to mimic Perl's, so I wonder if Perl does this too.

Comment: [Some docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `aa` is less than `z`. It has to do with how the letters are alphabetized.

See it in action: http://codepad.org/6sUkkKU5

It stops at `yz` after which `zz` evaluates to false for `$i <= 'z';`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski because `$i <= 'z';` is true.

Comment: I see it now... On my first reading, I though the `z` was _missing_ from the output as in `v w x y aa ab ac...`

Answer (score 1):

if this is other than theory; you could just use range

```
foreach (range('v', 'z') as $letter) {
    echo $letter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you used `<="z"`. When `$i == "z"`, and `$i++` is called, php is changing it from "z" to "aa", and `"aa" <= "z"` so the loop continues.

I hope you were looking just for an answer 'why' and not to how to write the loop.

Interesting finding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because the [increment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) is defined in one way, while [string comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is defined in another.